# Best practice to write Object.Object.Method

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call object.object.method like this.

yes, I can do, but I don't know it's a good way to do like this.

API file

```
export class ApiService {
     public customer = new Customer();
}

class Customer {
     public foo() {
          return "Bar";
     }
}
```

when I want to use Customer's method, I write like this.

Another file

```
const api = new ApiService();
api.customer.Foo();
```

Please advise me about this.

My English is not strong and I don't know keyword to search for this.

Thank you, guys.

edit : change Foo to foo (thanks : Nurbol Alpysbayev)

Comment: The code looks fine.  What is the problem?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Just ask for best practice to do like this.

Comment: A question I'd ask is, why do this in the first place? What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: I want to separate API class by use case (like customer, employee, etc) and call in 1 file (API Service)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine the way you are doing it. Although I would say that since you are only accessing the property "customer" in order to call a method, you could reduce the access to this property by putting it as private and creating a getter for this property. For instance:

```
export class ApiService {
     private _customer = new Customer();

     get customer(): Customer {
         return this._customer;
     }
}

class Customer {
     public foo() {
          return "Bar";
     }
}
```

This is a good practice and this way the customer's instance that is inside the ApiService class is read only, preventing other code to modify this instance by accident.

You still will be able to do this:

```
const api = new ApiService();
api.customer.foo();
```

Finally, as pointed in the previously posted comment, be consistent and start your methods with lowercase letters, following subsequent words with an starting uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfectly OK. Except you are not supposed to write methods capitalized. So change `Foo` to just `foo` and your are all good.